# ssh not working with yes

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I had to solve a fringe case lately where I had to add a number of server fingerprints to a user's `known_hosts` (the authorization is performed with a keypair). I thought the easiest solution would be to just call

```
yes yes | ssh *login@host*
```

. Surprisingly (to me at least), this doesn't work: `ssh` still asks whether to add the fingerprint, and requires manual input.

My question is: why is this the case, as in, **what is the mechanism underlying this behavior**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this prompt, `ssh` does not use the *stdin* & *stdout* streams – to avoid the prompt being mixed up with the remote command's input/output. (Imagine running `ssh host cat something.tar | tar x`, and suddenly having `tar x` complain about garbage in its input.)

Instead, `ssh` opens the special device `/dev/tty`, which always points to its "controlling terminal", writes the prompt there, and reads the answer from it.

---

For your problem specifically, OpenSSH comes with `ssh-keyscan`, a tool to grab public keys of many servers at once.

```
ssh-keyscan host1 host2 host3 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

*(I'm not sure whether you meant `known_hosts`, or actually needed `authorized_keys` here.)*

---

For the general case, the `expect` utility can be used to automate programs that normally do their I/O via tty.

Comment: Gah... of course I meant `known_hosts`, sorry about that. I suspected this might be something to do with `/dev/tty`, thanks for the clarification - and for the very comprehensive answer, addressing both the special and the general case.